# Variable number of inputs (from db) in a MVC request to C# backend?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, backend

Intro: Im saving in a DB a template of certain inputs that have to be taken as inputs, so it's not the same every time it operates, sometimes could be 2 others could be 12.

But still want to use a single post/get request (with variable numbers of arguments, that somehow i can recognize), is there a way of doing this in C# backend with and without using a json?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you're developing a Web API that sends/receives JSON data, it would make sense for the variable fields to be an additional JSON object within the request model of the API. Something along the lines of:

```
public class YourRequestApiModel
{
    public JsonDocument CustomData { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Then when sending your request, you could easily serialize an `IDictionary<string, object>` into a JSON structure to send to your API, e.g.:

```
{
   "customData": {
      "customerName": "Mario",
      "purchaseYear": 2020,
      "isFirstPurchase": true,
      "comments": null
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i updated the question since Stackoverflow thinks this is a opinion based question ( not sure how )